# Number of integral roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with integral coefficients. Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be three distinct integers such that $p(a) = p(b) = p(c) = -1$.
Find the number of integral roots of $p(x)$.

Comment: Any condition about $\deg p$?

Comment: What can you say about the structure of a polynomial with $p(a) = p(b) = p(c) = -1$?

Comment: Is it,find the number of integral roots or the minimum number of integral roots?

Comment: No there is nothing about the polynomial...

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $p(d)=0$ for some integer $d$.  Then $(x-d) \mid p(x)$.  Plugging in, we discover a very surprising fact about the integers $a-d$, $b-d$, and $c-d$...

Comment: I did not get it, sorry

Comment: @posthumus: Since $(x-d)\mid p(x)$ it follows that $(a-d)\mid p(a)=-1$. Therefore $(a-d)\mid -1$ and similarly $(b-d)\mid -1, (c-d)\mid -1$. Also $a-d, b-d, c-d$ are $3$ different integers. Now how many factors does $-1$ have?

Answer (score 4):

It deserves explicit emphasis that there is a frequently applicable idea at work here.

**Key Idea** $\ $ The possible factorizations of a polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]$ are constrained by the factorizations of the integer values that the polynomial takes. For a simple example, if some integer value has few factorizations (e.g. a unit $\,\pm1 $ or prime $p$) then the polynomial must also have few factors, asssuming that that the factors are distinct at the evaluation point. More precisely

If $\, f(x) = f_1(x)\cdots f_k(x)\,$ and $\,f_i\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ satisfy $\color{#0a0}{f_i(n) \ne f_j(n)}\,$ for $\,i\ne j,$ all $\,n\in \Bbb Z$

$\quad f(n) =\pm1\,\Rightarrow\, k\le 2\ $ else $1$ would have $\rm\,3\,\ \color{#0a0}{distinct}$ factors $\,f_1(n),f_2(n),f_3(n)$

$\quad f(n) = \pm p\,\Rightarrow\, k\le \color{#c00}4\ $ since a prime $p$ has at most $\,\color{#c00}4\,$ distinct factors $\,\pm1,\pm p$

Yours is a special case of the first (unit) case, where the $f_i$ are linear.

**Remark** $\ $ One can push the key idea to the hilt to obtain a simple *algorithm*  for polynomial factorization using factorization of its integer values and Lagrange interpolation. The ideas behind this algorithm are due in part to Bernoulli, Schubert, Kronecker. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26137/242) for references.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know factor theorem?

$p(a)=-1$ implies that the remainder when you divide $p(x)$ by $x-a$ is $-1$.

Using this theorem gives you a representation of $p(x)$.

Then, you'll know a 'surprising' fact (as User-33433 says) when you set an integer $x=d$ in $p(x)$.

By factor theorem, we get
$$p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)q(x)-1$$
where $q(x)$ is a polynomial with integral coefficients.

Comment: And now the interesting fact is that since there are at least *three* numbers such that $p(x)=-1$, you know for sure that one of $|d-a|$, $|d-b|$, $|d-c|$ is greater than $1$. Thus $p(d)=kq(d)-1=0$ would imply $q(d)=1/k$, witk $|k|>1$, but $d$ is assumed to be an integer, and $q$ has integer coefficients.

Comment: That's right. Hence...nice question.