# Problem related to polynomial which takes the same value for three inputs

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Let p(x) be a polynomial over the integers such that it takes 1 value at three different integers. Prove that it has no integral root.

MY ATTEMPT:

I couldn't really think of anything. I first thought that this polynomial cannot be linear or quadratic, as it takes the same values at more than two points(an application of the identity theorem for polynomials) but I dont know where to take that.

Comment: This is not clear.  If, say, $p(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$.  then $p(x)=0$ at each of $0,1,-1$ and of course it has integer roots.

Comment: Do you mean "value $1$" instead of "one value"?

Comment: I've written it exactly as it's worded in this book I have. There's nothing wrong with your counterexample, so this seems to be a wrong question. I'll delete this

Comment: Do they really write "1 value" where one should write "one value"?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's 'one value'

Comment: I'm guessing it is $P(a)=P(b)=P(c)=1$, show that $P(x)=0$ does not have an integer $x$ solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Well, that certainly makes sense,

Comment: @CalvinLin If they did mean that, it would be the most ambiguous of ambiguous wording. Regardless, I'll try the '1 as a value' version on my own

Comment: Related post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617426/58320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(See my comment for my interpretation of the question.)

**Hint:** For integer polynomials, $a-b \mid P(a) - P(b)$.

Comment: This hint makes the question laughable, if it truly did mean '1 as a value' and not 'one value'

Answer (score 3):

Let $q(x)=p(x)-1$

$q(a)=q(b)=q(c)=0$ for some integers $a$, $b$, $c$.

$q(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\cdot r(x)$, where $r(x)$ is some other polynomial over the integers.

When $p(x)=0$, $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\cdot r(x) = -1$

This is impossible since $a,b,c$ are integers, so the closest $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$  can be is $2$ or $-2$