# Factorization of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I need to find the roots of this polynomial $$2x^2-x^4-x=0.$$ I know that it is necessary the factorization to obtain $$-x(x-1)(x^2+x-1)=0.$$ I asked to factorize my polynomial to Mathematica. The last step to find the roots is to split the polynomial in three equations.

What kind of method of factorization could I use to do things like this? I also know that there are a lot of methods of factorization; could you suggest me the most useful, simplest to start with?

Thank you.

Comment: easy to see that $x=0$ and $x=1$ are the roots of the given equation. just factor it out.

Comment: With small coefficients and only a couple terms, trial and error using synthetic division would definitely be a good place to start.

Comment: Well, first of all, $x=0$ is obviously a root. Thus $2x^2- x^4 - x = 0 \Longrightarrow x(2x - x^3 -1) = 0$. Then it is easy to spot that $x=1$ is a root. Then, by long-division you can find the last factorization.

Comment: The [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_test) is often useful in school exercises.

Comment: @Santosh There are two more roots anyway $\frac12(-1\pm\sqrt5)$

Comment: @Charlie you can factor that using quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already solved most of this by yourself. If you have a high-degree polynomial (say $\deg P > 2$), try to find some roots by "guessing", for example $x=0$ and $x=1$ in your polynomial. Finding a root, to get another root, you do polynomial (long) division:
$$p(x) = 2x^2 - x^4 - x \stackrel!= 0$$
$x=0$ was found, so get
$$p_1(x) := \frac{p(x)}{x} = 2x - x^3-1\stackrel!=0$$
Guessing another root, $x=1$, you get
$$p_2(x) := \frac{p_1(x)}{x-1} = -x^2 -x +1 \stackrel!=0$$
From there ($\deg p_2 \le 2$) we can continue by completing the square:
$$-(x^2 + x + \frac14 - \frac54) \stackrel!=0$$
Thus
$$(x+\frac12)^2 \stackrel!= \frac54$$
$$\Rightarrow x \stackrel!= -\frac12 \pm \frac{\sqrt5}2$$
So your roots are:
$$\{x | p(x) = 0\} = \{0\} \cup \{x|p_1(x) = 0\} = \{0,1\} \cup \{x|p_2(x) = 0\} = \{0,1,-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt5}2, -\frac12 -\frac{\sqrt5}2\}$$

Answer (score 3):

After factoring out $x$ you obtain a cubic whose highest and lowest coefficients are $\color{#c00}{\pm1}.\,$ If it is reducible then it has a rational root, so by the Rational Root Test, that root can only be $\color{#c00}{\pm1}$. Thus for polynomials of this form you need only evaluate it a two points to complete the factorization.

Generally one can use the Rational Root Test to reduce the factorization of cubics to the testing of a finite number of rational roots, but there will be more than $2$ possible roots to check when the polynomial's high and low coeff's have many factors.

More generally, one can reduce polynomial factorization to the integer factorization of a few values taken by the polynomial, using [an old algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26137/242) due to Bernoulli, Schubert, Kronecker, Hausman. However, this is not efficient compared to modern algorithmic methods.

Comment: Where does it say the domain of factorization is $\mathbb Q$? Usually it is $\mathbb R$ and the present polynomial appears to be reducible over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @AlexR  Right, the domain is not specified in the OP. It could be over $\Bbb Q$, over its algebraic closure, or over $\Bbb R$.