# integral roots for $f(x) = 41$ if $f(x) = 37$ has 5 distinct integral roots.

Tags: number-theory

Given a polynomial $f(x)$ with integral coefficients and $f(x) = 37$ has 5 distinct integral roots, find the number of integral roots of $f(x) = 41$?

My Approach: Say $f(x) = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)(x-r_5)g(x) + 37$, where $r_i$ are the distinct integers.

Now for $f(x) = 41$ we have $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)(x-r_5)g(x) = 4$, so the factors can be $\pm 1, \pm2$ or $\pm 4$. Given $r_i$ are distinct at most two of them will give $\pm1$, then there can be both of $\pm 2$ or one of $\pm 4$. This is where I get lost, since even if I use all of $\pm1, \pm2$, I will be still be left with one $x-r_i$ factor. What about that? Does it matter that 37 and 41 are primes, or is it just a coincidence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of function is $f$? A polynomial? If so, does it have integer coefficients?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that omission.

Comment: Does the polynomial have $5$ roots, each of which are integral, or more roots, of which five are integral?

Comment: The question states that there are 5 distinct integers. Nothing is been said about whether they are only 5 integral solutions. + The coefficients of $f(x)$ are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially finished. There cannot be an integer $a$ such that $(a-r_1)(a-r_2)(a-r_3)(a-r_4)(a-r_5)g(a)=4$. For the $a-r_i$ are distinct integers, and no product of $5$ distinct integers can divide $4$.

Comment: So it had nothing to do with 37 and 41 being prime. Just their difference mattered. In general suppose I would have another number say 12 (instead of 4), I could have got maximum 5 integral roots (1, -1, 2, -2, 3). But can I say that the answer is 5 in this case?

Comment: Or $-8$, since $g(x)$ is at our disposal.  Again, there will not be a solution, but for numbers ricer in divisors than $8$, it will be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You changed the $8$ to $12$ while I was typing! Yes, the max number of integral roots is $5$ for the $12$ case. The roots can also be $1,-1,2,-2,-3$ if we construct $g$ so that $g(x)=-1$ at suitable places.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Finish by applying the following

**Key Idea** $\ $ The possible factorizations of a polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]$ are constrained by the factorizations of the integer values that the polynomial takes. For a simple example, if some integer value has few factorizations (e.g. a unit $\,\pm1 $ or prime $p$) then the polynomial must also have few factors, asssuming that that the factors are distinct at the evaluation point. More precisely

If $\, f(x) = f_1(x)\cdots f_k(x)\,$ and $\,f_i\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ satisfy $\color{#0a0}{f_i(n) \ne f_j(n)}\,$ for $\,i\ne j,$ all $\,n\in \Bbb Z$

$\quad \color{}{f(n) =\pm1}\,\Rightarrow\, k\le 2\ $ else $1$ would have $\rm\,3\,\ \color{#0a0}{distinct}$ factors $\,f_1(n),f_2(n),f_3(n)$

$\quad f(n) = \pm p\,\Rightarrow\, k\le \color{#c0f}4\ $ since a prime $p$ has at most $\,\color{#c0f}4\,$ distinct factors $\,\pm1,\pm p$

**Remark** $\ $ One can push the key idea to the hilt to obtain a simple *algorithm*  for polynomial factorization using factorization of its integer values and Lagrange interpolation. The ideas behind this algorithm are due in part to Bernoulli, Schubert, Kronecker. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26137/242) for references.

Comment: Thanks Bill for the generalization.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/680114/242) and [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/885628/242)