# Prove $f(x)=x^8-24 x^6+144 x^4-288 x^2+144$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

> How to prove $f(x)=x^8-24 x^6+144 x^4-288 x^2+144$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I tried Eisenstein criteria on $f(x+n)$ with $n$ ranging from $-10$ to $10$. None can be applied. I tried factoring over mod $p$ for primes up to $1223$. $f(x)$ is always reducible over these.

$f(x)$ has roots $\pm\sqrt{\left(2\pm\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3\pm\sqrt{3}\right)}$, and according to computation by PARI, should have Galois group isomorphic to the quaternion group. The splitting field of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)})$, and it contains $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}$, so we know $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is in the splitting field, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)})$ has degree $4$ or $8$.

I tried showing the degree is $8$ by showing that $(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})^2=(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})$ cannot have a solution with $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$, and got these equations:
$$a^2+2b^2+3c^2+6d^2=6$$
$$2ab + 6cd = 3$$
$$ac+2bd = 1$$
$$2ad+2bc = 1$$
which I'm unable to handle.

**Addendum:** now that I've solved this problem thanks to the answers, I found some additional related information:

In [A Rational Polynomial whose Group is the Quaternions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320711), a very similar polynomial, $$f(x)=x^8 - 72 x^6 + 180 x^4 - 144 x^2 + 36$$ is studied and its Galois group is proven to be the quaternion group. I subjected this polynomial, as well as two related ones: $f(\sqrt{x})$, $f(6\sqrt{x})/36$, to the same battery of tests (Eisenstein; mod p) and these tests also failed to show them to be irreducible. Maybe there's something common about these polynomials.

So I subjected $f(x)$ to the prime numbers test demonstrated by Robert Israel, and found that it is prime at $\pm\{7, 13, 23, 25, 49, 53, 55, 79, 91, 127, 139, 145, 151, 181, 239, 251, 277, 283, 319, 355, 379, 403, 413, 425, 473, 485, 595, 607, 623, 679, 733, 743, 779, 827, 851, 923, 965, ...\}$ and thus $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: +1 for casting a wide net.  At that point I would begin to look at some values of $f(x)$ at integer arguments.  The point is that $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is monic and therefore reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$..  So if $f(n)$ has few factors, it restricts the possible factors $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ accordingly (and sometimes one can show impossibility this way).

Comment: If the Galois Group is $Q_8$ reduction$\bmod p$ will not work, because there is no element of order $8$ in the group.

Comment: Note that $f(x+n)$ has coefficients $2^3n$ at $x^7$ and $2^43^2+n^8$ at $x^0$. So if a prime $p$ divides both, then $p$ also divides
$$2^3(2^43^2+n^8)-n^7(2^3n)=2^73^2,$$
so $p=2$ or $p=3$. But then also $p^2$ divides $2^43^2+n^8$, so Eisenstein cannot work on $f(x+n)$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your polynomial $f(x)$ takes prime (or $-$ prime) values at $x = \pm 1, \pm 7, \pm 11, \pm 13, \pm 23, \pm 67, \pm 85, \pm 109, \pm 145, \pm 197, \pm 205, \pm 209, \pm 241, \pm 373, \pm 397, \pm 403, \pm 421$.  That's $34$ points.  If it factored as $f(x)=g(x) h(x)$, one of $g$ and $h$ must be $\pm 1$ at at least $17$ of these $x$, and either $+1$ at at least $9$ points or $-1$ at at least $9$ points.  But a non-constant polynomial that takes the same value at $9$ points must have degree at least $9$, and $f$ has degree only $8$.

Comment: +1 I like it. Though it suffices to show that one of $g$ and $h$ has degree at least $8$, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I have never seen this argument before! Is it an argument that works for most irreducible polynomials, or just very special ones?

Comment: @Maud Ir's a special case of general method of Kronecker, Schubert et al. that relates the factorizations of a polynomial to the factorizations of the values it takes. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/680114/242) and its links for much more on these beautiful old ideas. Taken to the hilt they yield a polynomial factorization algorithm (though nowadays much more efficient algorithms are known).

Comment: If a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients and positive leading coefficient is irreducible and some of its values at positive integers are coprime,  then Bunyakovsky's conjecture says it takes infinitely many prime values at positive integers.  So yes, this should work for most irreducible polynomials.

Answer (score 8):

You just have to show that $f(x)$ is the **minimal** polynomial of $\eta=\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. to show that $\eta$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $8$. It is pretty straightforward to prove that $\eta^2$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $4$, hence we just need to rule out $\eta\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. If that were the case, for any large enough prime $p$ such that both $2$ and $3$ are quadratic residues ($p=24k+1$ is a sufficient condition) we would have that $(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})$ is a quadratic residue too. That contradicts quadratic reciprocity, and for an explicit counterexample, by considering $p=73$ we get that $21^2\equiv 3\pmod{p}$, $41^2\equiv 2\pmod{p}$ but $(2+41)\cdot(3+21)$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$. There are an infinite number of such counterexamples, hence $\eta\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\eta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

It is interesting to point out that "standard tricks" do not work here since $f(x)$ factors over any finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. This kind of polynomial is known as *Hilbert polynomial*, if I recall it correctly.

Comment: Indeed. This polynomial, and two of its "relatives" I've tested: $g(x) = f(\sqrt{x}) = x^4-24 x^3+144 x^2-288 x+144$, and $g(2x)/16=x^4-12 x^3+36 x^2-36 x+9$, are all reducible over any mod p I've tested (at least up to $p=541$).

Comment: Why does f(x)  split over any mod p?

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate: because for every prime $p$, at least one element of $\{2,3,6\}$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: If we know that $\eta^2$ is of degree $4$ then $\eta$ is of degree $4$ or $8$. We can rule out degree $4$ by proving that the polynomial has no factor of degree $4$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have proved that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)})/\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $8$, and that $\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)}$ is a root of $f$,   right ?

If so, then you may apply the following result:

**Lemma.** Let $K(\alpha)/K$ be an extension of degree $n$. If $f\in K[X] $ is a monic polynomial satisfies $f(\alpha)=0$ and
$\deg(f)=n,$ then $f=\mu_{\alpha,K}$ (the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$). In particular, $f$ is irreducible over $K.$

*Proof.* We have $[K(\alpha):K]=n=\deg(\mu_{\alpha,K}).$  Since $f(\alpha)=0$,  $\mu_{\alpha,K}\mid f$. But $f$ is monic and has degree $n$. Then $f=\mu_{\alpha,K}.$

Comment: Uh, no. I "know" that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)})/\mathbb{Q}$ has degree 8 (because PARI told me so), but to prove that I need to show $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Not necessarily. It is enough to prove that $\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)$ in not a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}).$

Comment: I know, but attempting to solve $(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})^2=(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})$ ends up a terrible mess.

Comment: Let $\alpha=\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)}$.
Then you proved that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, right ? Now, sending $\alpha$ to each root of $f$ yields $8$ distinct automorphisms of your galois extension, so its degree is at least $8$. But this is at most $8$ since $f $has degree $8$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.

Comment: To show that I can send $\alpha$ to each root of $f$, I need to use that the Galois group is transitive on the roots of $f(x)$. But to show it's transitive, I need to show $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: where can we find this lemma you stated @GreginGre

Answer (score 2):

This polynomial and the field $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $\alpha=\sqrt{(2+\sqrt2)(3+\sqrt3)}$ recur in exercises (it may be one of the simplest to describe fields with Galois group $Q_8$). I had a reason to look for a more elementary proof that $\alpha\notin\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ which is equivalent to the claim. Can't say that my argument would be as elementary as I want it to be. But it is different from those posted already, so I will share.

---

As a stepping stone I use reduction modulo five. The goal is to show that modulo five we have the factorization
$$\overline{f}(x)=(x^4+2)(x^4+x^2+2),\tag{1}$$
where both quartic factors are irreducible modulo $5$. It is, of course, trivial to verify this factorization. I sidestep a bit and explain a way to find this.

---

The field $K=\Bbb{F}_{5^2}=\Bbb{F}_5(\sqrt3)$ contains square roots for both $2$ and $3$. Because $3\equiv2^2\cdot2$ we can think of $\sqrt3$ as $2\sqrt2$, but this is really a choice of sign. With that choice made, in the field $K$ we have
$$\alpha^2=(2+\sqrt2)(3+\sqrt3)=6+3\sqrt2+2\sqrt3+\sqrt2\sqrt3=10++7\sqrt2=2\sqrt2.$$
Therefore $\alpha^4=3$ and consequently $\alpha^4+2=0$. This gives the first modular factor and we get the other by polynomial division.

Then I explain why the two quartic factors are irreducible modulo five. Because $\pm2$ are fourth roots of unity modulo five, any root of $x^4+2$ (in some extension field of $K$) must be a root of unity of order sixteen. But $\Bbb{F}_{5^4}$ is the smallest extension of $\Bbb{F}_5$ containing such roots of unity, and hence their minimal polynomial over the prime field is quartic. There are many ways to show that $u(x)=x^4+x^2+2$ is also irreducible over the prime field. The roots of $x^2+x+2$ in $K$ are $2\pm\sqrt2$, and the roots of $u(x)$ are square roots of these. It is easy to verify that neither of those has a square root in $K$, so they, too, reside in $\Bbb{F}_{5^4}\setminus\Bbb{F}_{5^2}$ proving the claim.

---

With the modulo five factorization clear, the rest is relatively simple. The factorization $(1)$ implies that the only possible way $f(x)$ can factor is as a product of two irreducible quartic polynomials $g(x),h(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$. We can further assume that the factors are monic.

Observe that $f(x)$ is even, so $f(x)=f(-x)=g(-x)h(-x)$. Because the factorization into irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is unique, we have two possibilities: either $g(-x)=h(x)$ (when also $h(-x)=g(x)$) or $g(-x)=g(x)$ and $h(-x)=h(x)$.

- It is impossible to have $g(-x)=h(x)$ because such a relation would persist after reduction modulo five, and $(1)$ shows that this is not the case.
- If $g(x)=g(-x)$ and $h(x)=h(-x)$, then both $g$ and $h$ contain even degree terms only. That is $g(x)=r(x^2)$ and $h(x)=s(x^2)$ for some quadratic polynomials $r(x),s(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$. This would imply that
  $$\alpha^2=(2+\sqrt2)(3+\sqrt3)$$
  is a root of a quadratic (either $r$ or $s$). But $\alpha^2$ is not an element of any of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$, $n=2,3,6$. By well-known Galois theory of $M=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ those are the only quadratic subfields of $M$, so we arrive at a contradiction in this case also.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $f(x) = f_1(x) f_2(x)$.

Note that $f(1) = - 23$, so one of $f_1(1)$, $f_2(1) = \pm 1$, and the other $\mp 23$.

The polynomial factors $\mod 5$ as $(x^4+2)(x^4 + x^2 + 2)$ ( see Jyrki's answer). Say we have $f_1(x)\equiv x^4 + 2$ and $f_2(x) \equiv x^4 + x^2 + 2 \mod 5$.  Now, $f_1(1) \equiv 1^4 + 2 = 3 \mod 5$, and $f_2(1) \equiv 1^4 + 1^2 + 2 \equiv -1 \mod 5$. We conclude that $f_1(1) = 23$, and $f_2(1) = -1$.

Now, $f(x)$ factors $\mod 3$ as $x^8$. We  have $f_1(x) \equiv x^4$, and $f_2(x) \equiv x^4 \mod 3$. This implies $f_1(1), f_2(1) \equiv 1 \mod 3$.  We got a contradiction

$\bf{Added:}$ Another proof:  Assume that $(2+\sqrt{2})(3+ \sqrt{3})$ is  a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$. Taking the norm to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ we get
$(2+\sqrt{2})^2 (3+ \sqrt{3})(3-\sqrt{3})$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so $6$ is, contradiction.

Comment: This is a nice combination of ideas. Thanks for sharing :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen:  Thank you!  :-)