# Suppose p(x) is a polynomial with integer coefficients. Show that if p(a) =1 for some integer a then p(x) has at most two integer roots.

Tags: polynomials

Problem :

Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. Show that if $p(a) =1$ for some integer $a$ then $p(x)$ has at most two integer roots.

Let $p(x)$ be a cubic polynomial such that $p(x) =ax^3+bx^2+cx +d =0 $

Let $p(\alpha) =a\alpha^3 +b \alpha^2 + c\alpha +d =1 $  ( as per the question) .

where $a,b,c$ are integers.

Now how to prove the  given problem please suggest thanks.....

Comment: Is this for a class? If so, what theorems have you covered? Have you discussed the rational root theorem?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ It is the special case $\,\color{#c00}{f(n)=1} $ of the following general

**Key Idea** $\ $ The possible factorizations of a polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]$ are constrained by the factorizations of the integer values that the polynomial takes. For a simple example, if some integer value has few factorizations (e.g. a unit $\,\pm1 $ or prime $p$) then the polynomial must also have few factors, asssuming that that the factors are distinct at the evaluation point. More precisely

If $\, f(x) = f_1(x)\cdots f_k(x)\,$ and $\,f_i\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ satisfy $\color{#0a0}{f_i(n) \ne f_j(n)}\,$ for $\,i\ne j,$ all $\,n\in \Bbb Z$

$\quad \color{#c00}{f(n) =\pm1}\,\Rightarrow\, k\le 2\ $ else $1$ would have $\rm\,3\,\ \color{#0a0}{distinct}$ factors $\,f_1(n),f_2(n),f_3(n)$

$\quad f(n) = \pm p\,\Rightarrow\, k\le \color{#c0f}4\ $ since a prime $p$ has at most $\,\color{#c0f}4\,$ distinct factors $\,\pm1,\pm p$

Yours is a special case of the first (unit) case, where the $f_i$ are linear.

**Remark** $\ $ One can push the key idea to the hilt to obtain a simple *algorithm*  for polynomial factorization using factorization of its integer values and Lagrange interpolation. The ideas behind this algorithm are due in part to Bernoulli, Schubert, Kronecker. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26137/242) for references.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Suppose your cubic has three integer roots $\;u_1,u_2,u_3\;$ , then

$$p(x)=a(x-u_1)(x-u_2)(x-u_3)$$

It is given though that

$$1=p(\alpha)=a(\alpha-u_1)(\alpha-u_2)(\alpha-u_3)\;,\;\alpha\in\Bbb Z$$

But all the factors above are integers, so either all are $\;1\;$  or two exactly are $\;-1\;$ or...

Comment: What about the $a$ coefficient? Suppose that is greater than 1?