# Algebraic process to find numbers so that $xy=45$ and $x+y=18$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Can someone help me with the following question?

The sum of two numbers is $18$ and their product is $45$. Find the numbers.

I know that the answer is $15$ and $3$. But how do I find that answer algebraically?
It tried doing it as $x+y=18$ and $xy=45$ and then $x= 18-y$ and I substituted in $xy=45$. I got it as $(18-y)y =45$, and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You need the pq-formula.

Comment: What is that formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p+q=18 \\
\text{& } pq=45$

So,

$p=\large\frac{45}q$

$\frac{45}q+q=18$

$q^2+45-18q=0$

$q^2-15q-3q+45=0$

$q(q-15)-3(q-15)=0$

$(q-3)(q-15)=0$

Or, q is either 3 or 15.

That makes p either 15 or 3.

Comment: Thank you ! That was even more help .

Answer (score 6):

A nice method for this type of problem is to note that since the two numbers add to $18$, they may be expressed as $9-a$ and $9+a$.  Then the product being $45$ gives
$$(9-a)(9+a)=45$$
$$81-a^2=45$$
$$a^2=36$$
$$a=\pm 6$$
The two values of $a$ give $x$ and $y$ as $9-6$ and $9+6$; or as $9-(-6)$ and $9+(-6)$.  That is, $3$ and $15$ in either case.

Comment: WoW! Never seen that approach before. +1

Comment: @paw88789 : very symmetrical and elegant!

Comment: @hypergeometric: Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

While one can rotely apply the quadratic formula, their is a simpler way. Let the roots be  $\, r,s.\,$ $\,(x\!-\!r)(x\!-\!s) = x^2\!-(r\!+\!s)x+rs = x^2\!-18x+45,\,$ so $\,r,s\,$ are *integers* by the Rational Root Test. But there are few *integer* factorizations $\,45 = rs.\,$ One quickly finds the one with $\,r\!+\!s = 18\,$

Optimizing further: $\,3\,$ divides the root sum,  $\,3^2$ divides root product $\,\Rightarrow 3\,$ divides both roots, because $\, X^2 - 18 X + 45 = 9(x^2 - 6 x + 5),\ X = 3x,\,$ so we reduce to root sum $ = 6,\,$ product $= 5,\,$ which is easy to solve, since $\,5\,$ has only *two* factorizations $\, 5\cdot 1\,$ and $\ {-}5(-1).\,$

**Remark** $\ $ We factored the polynomial by exploiting the fact that its constant term (= *value* at $\,0)$ had few factorizations. This works much more generally, namely

**Key Idea** $\ $ The possible factorizations of a polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]$ are constrained by the factorizations of the integer values that the polynomial takes. For a simple example, if some integer value has few factorizations (e.g. a unit $\,\pm1 $ or prime $p$) then the polynomial must also have few factors, asssuming that that the factors are distinct at the evaluation point. More precisely

If $\, f(x) = f_1(x)\cdots f_k(x)\,$ and $\,f_i\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ satisfy $\color{#0a0}{f_i(n) \ne f_j(n)}\,$ for $\,i\ne j,$ all $\,n\in \Bbb Z$

$\quad \color{}{f(n) =\pm1}\,\Rightarrow\, k\le 2\ $ else $1$ would have $\rm\,3\,\ \color{#0a0}{distinct}$ factors $\,f_1(n),f_2(n),f_3(n)$

$\quad f(n) = \pm p\,\Rightarrow\, k\le \color{#c0f}4\ $ since a prime $p$ has at most $\,\color{#c0f}4\,$ distinct factors $\,\pm1,\pm p$

You can find specific applications of these ideas in [some prior posts here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+Schubert+Kronecker.)

**Remark** $\ $ One can push the key idea to the hilt to obtain a simple *algorithm*  for polynomial factorization using factorization of its integer values and Lagrange interpolation. The ideas behind this algorithm are due in part to Bernoulli, Schubert, Kronecker. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26137/242) for references.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph (and in particular the use of the rational root test), I have a hard time thinking of circumstances in which the use of 'number' with no qualifiers (as in the question) would imply rational but _not_ already imply integer; this seems superfluous to me. (And of course, if you don't know that $x$ and $y$ are rational you can't apply the RRT in the first place.)

Comment: @Steven Quick checks for "obvious" (rational) roots is usually the first thing one tries for problems like this. With practice, one can do the above in less than $10$ seconds of *mental* arithmetic, so little time is lost even if it does not apply. Moreover, as I wrote, the idea extends to a simple *algorithm* to factor polynomials (though inefficient compared to more sophisticated modern algorithms)

Answer (score 2):

As [Travis says](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910898/algebraic-process-to-find-numbers-so-that-xy-45-and-xy-18#comment1879678_910898), you can use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):
$$18y - y^2 = 45$$
$$y^2 - 18y + 45 = 0$$
$$y = 9 \pm \sqrt{9^2-45} = 9 \pm 6$$