# Divisibility in a certain ring and divisibility in integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

Divisibility in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ implies divisibility in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Let $P(x,y)=Q(x,y)\cdot R(x,y)$ with $P,Q,R$ polynomials with integer coefficients, evaluating in $(x,y)=(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ clearly gives a divisibility relation in $\mathbb{Z}$. More precisely, my question is:

May I show that a polynomial $P(x,y)$ is not divisible by $Q(x,y)$ assuming that it's, and later to evaluate in a particular pair $(a,b)$ getting not divisibility in integers, and hence a contradiction with assumption?

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque, but I'm referring to polynomials in two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works fine, e.g. if $\ x\mid y\ $ in $\,\Bbb Z[x,y]\,$ then $\ 0\mid 1\ $ in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ by evaluating at $\,x,y = 0,1.$

**Remark** $\ $ Often one can deduce much information about divisibility of polynomials by examining the divisibility of their evaluations. For example, the possible factorizations of a polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]$ are constrained by the factorizations of the integer values that the polynomial takes. For a simple example, if some integer value has few factorizations (e.g. it is a unit $\,\pm1 $ or prime $p$) then the polynomial must also have few factors, asssuming that that the factors are distinct at the evaluation point. More precisely

If $\, f(x) = f_1(x)\cdots f_k(x)\,$ and $\,f_i\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ satisfy $\color{#0a0}{f_i(n) \ne f_j(n)}\,$ for $\,i\ne j,$ all $\,n\in \Bbb Z$

$\quad \color{#c00}{f(n) =\pm1}\,\Rightarrow\, k\le 2\ $ else $1$ would have $\rm\,3\,\ \color{#0a0}{distinct}$ factors $\,f_1(n),f_2(n),f_3(n)$

$\quad f(n) = \pm p\,\Rightarrow\, k\le \color{#c0f}4\ $ since a prime $p$ has at most $\,\color{#c0f}4\,$ distinct factors $\,\pm1,\pm p$

One can push the key idea to the hilt to obtain a simple *algorithm*  for polynomial factorization using factorization of its integer values and Lagrange interpolation. The ideas behind this algorithm are due in part to Bernoulli, Schubert, Kronecker. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26137/242) for references.

Comment: Polynomials must have two variables

Comment: @bob Of course more complex examples are easy to construct, e.g.   $\ x+y\, \nmid\, 1+xf(x,y)\ $ else $\ 0\mid 1\,$ by evaluating at $\,x,y = 0.\, $ It doesn't matter how many variables you have since (compositions of) evaluation maps remain ring homomorphisms.