# Factoring polynomial

Tags: factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I have a polynomial, let's say $p(x)=x^5+x^4+x^2+x+2$ (or any other polynomial with rational coefficients). What is the general recommended way of factoring it into irreducible factors (in $Z[x]$, $Q[x]$, $Z_n[x]$, $F_n$, etc.)?

I've tried to use *Horner's method* on $p(x)$, but it does not have integer roots. I've studied the theory around finite fields for a few days, but I still don't understand how can I factor polynomials or show that the polynomial is irreducible in a given field. Can you possibly recommend me some good website/book with examples how to approach this kind of problems?

Comment: Factoring by hand is hard but there are algorithms. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials).
See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26135/is-factoring-polynomials-as-hard-as-factoring-integers. For your example, you can ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B2).

Answer (score 1):

Thr best currently known algorithm is the one due to Mark van Hoeij, described in [this nice paper by Kluners.](https://www2.math.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Mathematik/AG-Klueners/publications/factor_lll.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, but I've just started with finite fields this semester, so I'm not looking for the *best currently known algorithm*. I'm looking for a simple way which can be used in an exam.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no method I know that is both general and easy to use by hand...