# Factoring cubic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

Trying to figure this one out but I see no logical approach to this at all.

$$x^3-3x^2-4x+12$$

I know that it will be 3 parts most likely and that each will start with x but beyond that I will just guess at evrything most likely. How do I factor something weird like this?

Comment: $x^2(x-3)-4(x-3)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HINT** $\rm\quad f(x)\ =\ x^3 - a\ x^2 - b\ x + a\:b\: \  =\: \ x^2\ (x- a) - b\ (x - a)\ =\ \cdots$

Alternatively, by the [Rational Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), the only possible rational roots are integer factors of $\rm\:a\:b\:.\:$ But clearly $\rm\ x = a\ $ is a root since it makes the first and last pair of terms cancel out. Therefore, since $\rm\:f(a) = 0\:$ we deduce that $\rm\:f(x)\:$ has the factor $\rm\:x-a\:$ by the Factor Theorem.

For more efficient  polynomial factorization algorithms see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/904/242) and the following survey.

Kaltofen, E. [Factorization of Polynomials,](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.7916&rep=rep1&type=pdf) pp. 95-113 in:
Computer Algebra, B. Buchberger, R. Loos, G. Collins, editors, Vienna, Austria, 1982.

Comment: This looks like a helpful comment but really it all goes over my head and I have no idea what is even being discussed. I am not familiar with much of the language being used.

Comment: @Jordan What is unfamiliar? What is your math background?

Comment: I have taken college algebra a couple times and calculus once, studying again for calc1. I am just having trouble following the discussion I have no idea where I am supposed to learn all this stuff I have never taken a class that taught this kind of material.

Comment: @Jordan But what *precisely* is it that you don't understand above.

Comment: The Rational Root test, integer factors of a b, x=a is a root, f(a)=0,  f(x) has the factor x-a by the Factor Theorem, polynomial factorization algorithms, and then a lot of stuff from that link.

Comment: @Jordan Concerning the rational root test. The independent term of the
polynomial $P(x)=x^{3}-3x^{2}-4x+12$ is $12$ and the coefficient of $x^{3}$
is $1$. The divisors of $12$ are $1,2,3,4,6,12$. By the rational root
theorem the possible rational (integer in this case) roots of $P(x)=0$ may only be these divisors
and their symmetric ones. We can e.g. compute $P(1)=6\neq 0$ and then $P(2)=0
$. Since $2$ is a zero of $P(x)$ we can find $p,q$ such that

$P(x)=x^{3}-3x^{2}-4x+12=(x-2)(x^{2}+px+q)$.

Comment: @Jordan Note that $\rm\:a,b\:$ denote arbitrary integers above. The point was to generalize your example slightly to make the innate structure more evident. Here's a [Factor Theorem link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) These are topics that are normally taught in high school algebra courses.

Comment: @Jordan ...  the integer factors of $ab=12$  are $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 12$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $x^3-3x^2-4x+12 = x^2(x-3) - 4(x-3) = (x^2-4)(x-3)$.  So your roots are $x=-2,2,$ and $3$.

Comment: I would never notice that.

Comment: Sure you would.  With a lot more practice. ;-)

Comment: I only have a couple weeks before I attempt calculus again not sure how much practice I can get in.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$
x^3-3x^2-4x+12 = x^2(x - 3) - 4(x-3) = (x^2 - 4)(x-3) = (x-2)(x+2)(x-3).
$$

Answer (score 1):

x^3-3x^2-4x+12

When you have four terms in a polynomial, first look to see if you can group them two at a time and pull things out. For this one you can.

(x^3-3x^2)-4(x-3)
= x^2(x-3)-4(x-3)
= (x-3)(x^2-4)
= (x-3)(x+2)(x-2)