# Solving a polynomial with modular arithmetic.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

$x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$

Assume that $a,b,c,d,e$ are not arbitrary and that they are known.

I was wondering if it were possible to reduce or 'simplify' this using some modular arithmetic.

It would become something along the lines of $$(1+zm)x^5+(a+zn)x^4+(b+zo)x^3+(c+zp)x^2+(d+zq)x+e+zr\equiv0\pmod{z}$$

And I could choose $m,n,o,p,q,r,z$ to transform the given polynomial into another polynomial that I had already solved.

The solution to the above could then be used to find the exact solutions through trial and error, however, the exact solutions could first be approximated, with the exact solutions found afterwards as a subset of the solutions produced by the above polynomial?

Or perhaps we could attempt to solve $f(x)=0$ with $f(x)\equiv g(x)\pmod{(x-r)}$ and attempt to have $g(x)=0$. (I imagine this wouldn't work, but who knows?)

Is it possible to do?  Can it make a seemingly unfactorable polynomial factorable?

Comment: Factorable over what field?

Comment: @BenS. Um, I don't think I quite know?  I can say I'll accept solutions $x\in\mathbb{C}$, but I haven't learned much field theory and group theory or related subjects.

Comment: For example, the integers modulo $p$ form a field. Sometimes polynomials can be factored over some of these fields but not over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, but every polynomial can be factored completely over $\mathbb{C}$. For example, $x^2+1$ can be factored as $(x+1)^2$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but not factored in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BenS. That's not true.  Not all polynomials can be factored completely over $\mathbb{C}$, that's why we have Galois Theory.  If I am correct.

Comment: Whoa, wait, is this the basis of field theory?

Comment: See the second sentence here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Comment: @BenS. I meant that it doesn't have a closed form.

Comment: Galois theory has more to do with the symmetries of the roots.

Comment: Ahhh...yes, that is true. Not all have a closed form involving just addition, subtraction, multiplication, and $n$-th roots. But over $\mathbb{C}$ every polynomial can nonetheless be factored completely, though figuring out exactly what the factors are is the difficult part.

Comment: @BenS. Well, my question is whether or not using modular arithmetic can help.

Comment: Yes, we can factor polynomials over $\,\Bbb Z\,$ by using modular factorizations, Hensel and CRT lifting. This is a standard technique in computer algebra, e.g. see the [citations here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/904/242)